# Java Unicode Characters in iText PDF

Tags: android, itext

I am trying to add some special characters in my Android App Studio generated PDF, but other than °, none of the characters are visible in iText generated pdf. Please help!

```
Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 15f, 15f, 35f, 25f);
String outPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Bar_Fixed_Compressive.pdf";
try {
     PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream(outPath));
     doc.open();
     doc.add(new Paragraph("On increase in the temperature of the bar by " +mEditText4b1113.getText().toString() +"\u00B0 C, the uniform thermal " +
                            "strain is given by, \n " +"\u03B5 =" +"\u03B1" +"x T " ));
     doc.close();
}
```

Comment: When you don't define a font object, the default font Helvetica is used. Helvetica doesn't know how to render the special characters you want to add. You need to provide a different font. This is explained in great detail on the official web site: https://developers.itextpdf.com/tutorial/using-fonts-pdf-and-itext

Comment: Will FreeSans work then ? I am in App Studio for Mac and facing difficulties in adding the font from 'res' file. How do I add this font with Java code?